# Can't get 1280x800 screen resolution

Tags: hardware, intel-graphics

How can I enable 1280x800 screen resolution? I started to have this issue once I switched from Windows XP to Ubuntu 11.10. Are there any drivers I need to download? I checked and Ubuntu says there are none available for me.

System:

Dell Inspiron B130
512 MB RAM
40 GB HDD
Intel Celeron M Processor

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the "xserver-xorg-video-intel" package if it's not already installed. 
You can do this via Software Center or  *sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel* in the terminal. 
Then log out and back in again, or reboot.

If that's not working check out [this](http://www.linwik.com/wiki/configuring+the+intel+graphics+media+accelerator+900-950+for+linux) page.

Hope it works.